# In MariaDB how do I select the top 10 rows from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb, top-n

I just read online that MariaDB (which SQLZoo uses), is based on MySQL. So I thought that I can use ROW_NUMBER() function

However, when I [try this function in SQLZoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Self_join) :

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT  * FROM route
) TEST7
WHERE ROW_NUMBER()  < 10
```

then I get this error :

> Error: FUNCTION gisq.ROW_NUMBER does not exist

Comment: possible duplicate of [ROW\_NUMBER() in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Comment: MariaDB is based on *MySQL*, not *MS SQL*.

Comment: @tadman - ah, I mixed it up then, apologies.  thanks !

Comment: The [MySQL 5.6 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/) is pretty thorough and has a function index. It's something any developer should have bookmarked and at the ready. If you're ever curious if a function exists, look there first. Stack Overflow is a good second place to check when you're stumped.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the `limit` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM route LIMIT 10
```

This can, of course, be used on a sorted query too:

```
SELECT * FROM route ORDER BY some_field LIMIT 10
```

Comment: In fact, there's almost no point in it not being on a sorted query!

Answer (score 2):

use `LIMIT 10` at the end of your statement.

See the [MySQL SELECT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).